# Extracting XML from HTML file from URL in java

Tags: java, html, xml

I have a piece of work where I need to extract the HTML content from URL. And in HTML file contains the href link which contains an XML data. I need to extract it and parse it to fetch xml data.

Currently I have implemented code for extracting data from URL in html. My proble is how to fetch xml from HTML.

HTML format is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Directory Contents</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <h1>Directory Contents</h1>

    <table class="sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size <small>(bytes)</small></th>
          <th>Date Modified</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          <tr class='file'>
            <td><a href='/celldetails/loc/0808_0445_loc_results.xml'>0808_0445_loc_results.xml</a></td>
            <td><a href='/celldetails/loc/0808_0445_loc_results.xml'>XML File</a></td>
            <td><a href='/celldetails/loc/0808_0445_loc_results.xml'>0</a></td>
            <td sorttable_customkey='20140808044504'><a href='/celldetails/loc/0808_0445_loc_results.xml'>Aug 8 2014 4:45 AM</a></td>
          </tr>
```

I need to extarct '0808_0445_loc_results.xml' from HTML file.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers 
MS

Comment: As almost no HTML code out there is really valid XML you might want to use something like tagsoup to convert your HTML to valid XML. Then you can use an XPath processor of your choosing and use an XPath as Romski suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath to find the href node that contains the text "0808_0445_loc_results.xml". Then use the value of the node construct a URL to load the XML.

```
//@href[contains(.,'0808_0445_loc_results.xml')]
```